# Cypress: How to access wp-admin in cypress?

Tags: wordpress, cypress

Anybody here is automating Wordpress in wp-admin? I just keeps getting is error

**Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.**

i tried this code but i got the same error when logging in. i can't access the dashboard

```
beforeEach('Setcookies', () => {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('wordpress_{hash}','wordpress_logged_in_[hash]')
})
```

Comment: Maybe is he `hash` dynamic. Have you verified that it changes each time you make a visit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing a bit of automation within the dashboard and got things working by using the [regex powers](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Preserve-RegExp) of the `Cypress.Cookies.defaults()` method.

So my test looks something like:

```js
context('Test Dashboard', () => {
  before(() => {
    // This is a custom command that logs in a user for me
    cy.loginAs('user')

    /**
     * This is responsible for keeping the user logged in
     * throughout the test
     */
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
      preserve: /wordpress_|wordpress_logged_in_/,
    })
  })

  it('loads the Dashboard', () => {
    cy.visit('/wp-admin');
    cy.get('h1').contains('Dashboard');
  })
})
```